# Why is FunWebProducts flooding my server?

Tags: security, log-files, spam, ddos, flooding

I have received 47 000 hits in the past couple of hours from a single domain. I researched FunWebProducts but it seems to be some kind of a plugin, not sure how this is possible?

```
89.70.25.120 - - [03/Sep/2012:07:19:12 +0200] "POST /user/login HTTP/1.0" 200 18127 "http://xxxyyyzzzsitename.com/user/login" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; FunWebProducts; MRA 4.6 (build 01425); .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
89.70.25.120 - - [03/Sep/2012:07:19:13 +0200] "POST /user/login HTTP/1.0" 200 18127 "http://xxxyyyzzzsitename.com/user/login" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; FunWebProducts; MRA 4.6 (build 01425); .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
89.70.25.120 - - [03/Sep/2012:07:19:14 +0200] "POST /user/login HTTP/1.0" 200 18127 "http://xxxyyyzzzsitename.com/user/login" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; FunWebProducts; MRA 4.6 (build 01425); .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
```

Comment: That looks like a spam bot to me.  It could be a brute force bot but I'd want to see more traffic to be sure.  Whenever you see "MSIE 6.0" these days, it's nearly always a bot.

Comment: How could we possibly know why *anyone* is flooding your server?

Comment: I am more curious why FunWebProducts would do such a thing. I guess if an individual wants a reason they will surely find one :D FunWebProducts looked like a legit product...I now understand this may have been a fake header for a spamcrapper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't ever trust the `User-Agent` string. It is ridiculously easy to fake.

And if you haven't banned that IP address already, go do it now.

Comment: But why would someone fake a unique, obscure piece of software that is apparently associated with spyware?

Comment: If you want to fake a user-agent, I would expect someone to spoof a common user-agent string.

Comment: Common user-agent strings are _too_ common, I suppose.